# Visual Studio 2015 Winforms bug - Error when setting a breakpoint

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Create a WinFrm app - Paste this code into a button click handler and create a global variable bool keepGoing -  set a breakpoint on Thread.Sleep(500) and run it. The program will stop working but  I don't know why. Using .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 10

```
    bool keepGoing = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
        {
            while (keepGoing)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);//set breakpoint here

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The app stops working.

Comment: It doesn't even reach the catch part. Apparently, this code should work fine (it does in VS 2012). It seems that you have found a bug.

Comment: I did it....and nothing happened. It works as expected, with and without breakpoints. What do you mean by "the program will break"? Any error message?

Comment: if you make the keepGoing variable local it works fine.

Comment: @RenéVogt It happens only in VS 2015. It works until you set a breakpoint in `Thread.Sleep` and step into (F11), when it crashes.

Comment: Which version exactly? RTM version? Which update? Which .NET framework? Run in Release mode or debug mode? The question leaves too many questions open

Comment: No repro.  Click the Download link on [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx).

Comment: It works fine here in VS2015 14.0.23107.0 WinForms .NET Debug build

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have exactly your same version and I can see it.

Comment: Can the downvoters please try to understand the problem first? The code works, but it crashes when trying to debug it. Just copy the code exactly as it is and set a break point in Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Ok tried it again with the exact break point and F11: no such behaviour in VS2013... hopefully they fix it until we roll out VS2015 ;)

Comment: @varocarbas: so you can reproduce it? If so, which VS version, which .NET version, which OS? I have tried it, I have debugged it, I stepped into it and everything is fine

Comment: @ThomasWeller As said, I have exactly the same VS version than you have (14.0.23107.0; it is Community, but this shouldn't matter, at least in theory), my OS is Windows 10. I start a new Winforms project, put a button on it and, in its `Click` event, I include this code (+ the global variable). It runs fine. If I set the breakpoint where indicated, It reaches there without any problem; if I press F11 (to allow the code to step into; to go to the next iteration, in this case) the application stops working. All this happens in debug mode; in release mode, the behaviour is still more weird...

Comment: @ThomasWeller.... and the code is not even reached. In both cases, I am using the "All CPU" option (= 32bit). Every single time when I have emulated these conditions the described error has appeared (= I am completely sure that it exists). I have also done tests with other VS versions (2010 and 2012, both Ultimate) where everything works fine. I hope that you will not need any further clarification regarding my exact conditions (i.e., the ones under which you can trigger the described error as many times as you wish) :)

Comment: @varocarbas: my OS is Windows 7 SP1 x64

Comment: @ThomasWeller Then I guess that Windows 10 has also something to say (mine is also 64bit, but I did my tests by building the project using the 32bit alternative). I have already seen (the same version of) various pieces of software working differently in Windows 7/10. In any case, the OP has already confirmed that the last VS 2015 version (update 1) doesn't have the problem anymore (and I guess that his conditions are equivalent to mine, so I should stop seeing this problem. Not in hurry to upgrade because I mostly use VS 2012). In summary: this whole situation is not too relevant.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I took a look at your profile and you are precisely a tester, so shouldn't all this be more or less evident to you? Isn't precisely the typical behaviour of a tester to tell (and insist over and over) to someone like me (= a developer; additionally mostly focused on algorithms and highly-controlled situations, where there are almost no incompatibilities) that these things happen much than what we think? That I have always to test all the possible scenarios to make completely sure? I mean... don't get offended, but this whole conversation seems like the opposite world :)

Comment: @varocarbas: I don't see a problem in all the conversation here, also with my role as a tester. The question was unclear. As a tester I try to reproduce it and I wasn't able to do so, because major information was missing. So I requested that information with a comment. I have received the information and it is now at least possible that the OS is part of the problem. And yes, I'm one of those people telling developers that I have to test on different hardware and different OS to guarantee that the customer gets a product that works - and this usually takes more time than available.

Comment: @ThomasWeller There is no problem at all. I just found it curious/ironic :)

Answer (score 2):

I just updated Visual Studio now running:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

I am happy to say this bug looks like it has been fixed.